# Pandas: Group values based on date

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have the following data frame:

| Index | DEAL ID | DATE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 432 | 20200405 |
| 2 | 522 | 201800405 |
| .. | 632 | 20180409 |
| 434 | 9332 | 20190405 |

No I want to count, how many deals have been created in 2018, 2019 etc.

Already tried to use groupby for this:

`df_DATE['DEAL_ID'].groupby(df_DATE.DATE)`

Any idea how to fix this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TRY:**

```
new_df = df.groupby(pd.to_datetime(df.DATE, format='%Y%m%d').dt.year).agg({'DEAL' : 'count'})
```

Comment: Thank you! 

Just to make sure that I understood your solution:

1. You group the dataframe based on the DATE column. Before that, you are converting the column to a datetime object with the format ('%Y%m%d') 
-> But why are you adding."dt.year"?

2. Using the groups you aggregate the DEAL column. Could I use instead of 'count' for example 'mean'?

Answer (score 2):

You can add a column that has the year and then group by this column.

```
df_DATE["year"] = df_DATE.DATE.apply(lambda x: x[:4])
counts = df_DATE.groupby("year").size()
```

Assuming your `DATE` column is a string.

Comment: Thank you! Works perfect :)

So the lambda function adds a new column (year) and then it copies the first four char (the year) into this column. Later on it groups all rows and counts the values, right?

Comment: yes, also `size()` works better for your use case as you get a series with index `year` and the size of each group.